# Spring integration queue, any way to get current queue size?

Tags: spring-integration

We have scenario that lots of message from external system need to be processed async, current design is to have a job wake up every 5 mins to pull msg from external system, and then persist raw msg, and then send msg id to ExecutorChannel, so consumer(potentially many) can consume from channel.

The problem we are facing is how to deal with system crash while msgs in queue, somehow every time job wake up, we will need to look into our DB to find out if there is any raw msgs not in queue already.

The easiest way is to query current queue size and find out if there are more raw msg than msg in queue. So question I have is:  is any API for ExecutorChannel to find out size of queue? or any other suggestion?

Thx
Jason

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration itself doesn't maintain a queue within an ExecutorChannel; the messages are executed by the underlying Executor.

If you are using a Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor which is dedicated to the channel, you could drill down to the channel's underlying ThreadPoolTaskExecutor's ThreadPoolExecutor, and get a handle to its BlockingQueue (getQueue()) and get it's count.

However, you'd have to add the active task count as well.

The total count would be approximate, though because the ThreadPoolExecutor has no atomic method to get a count of queued and active tasks.